# How to detect tomcat deploy failure in Jenkins

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, deployment, jenkins

I just set up Jenkins CI for building web applications(Spring Framework).

After job builds with new commits, post action triggered to deploy built .war file to tomcat by deploy plugin.

In this case, Is there any way to detect deploy failure? so that I can use command to deal with deploy failure(not build failure)?